# Elastic Beanstalk server has duplicate upstream "nodejs" and sometimes fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My elastic beanstalk node.js server sometimes works when I deploy it and then after some time it fails and loses connection with the subdomain I connected it to.

I needed https and a certificate so I added a subdomain like api.website.com so I could have it.

The error I get in my logs is

`duplicate upstream "nodejs" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf:9`

And then when I just tried redeploying after I added the https redirect config file: https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/blob/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/security-configuration/https-redirect/nodejs/https-redirect-nodejs.config

I get this message in the logs

`duplicate MIME type "text/html" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf:50`

And my default environment url works, but my api subdomain does not work.

When I go to my url I see

`api.*******.com’s server IP address could not be found.`

I connected my subdomain and the nameservers to my domain provider DNS and it works sometimes. My main url which is also connected to an elastic beanstalk environment works with no issues.

I have no idea what the problem is.

It sometimes works, and then after some time it fails and the subdomain loses connection or something. I also see the "duplicate upstream" error sometimes.

Any idea?

Comment: I can give a partial answer. `gzip_types` includes `text/html` by default, so the author of the config file was wrong to include it on line 81. If you delete that single type, the "duplicate MIME type" warning will stop. I'm getting the same "duplicate upstream" message and not yet sure how to fix it.

Comment: I just get the exact same issue. For now i am trying again but no solution.